# C++ : nameable objects belonging to an instance of a class, and stored in it

Tags: c++, indexing, command-line-arguments, stdstring, compile-time

I am trying to make it possible for a programmer (who uses my library) to create nameable instances of type `X` that are stored inside an instance of class `C` (or at least are exclusive to that instance).
These are the only two (ugly) solutions I have managed to come up with (needless to say, I am just picking up C++)

**1)**

```
class C
{
public:
    class XofC
    {
    public:
        XofC() = delete;
        XofC(C& mom)
        {
            mom.Xlist.emplace_front();
            ref = Xlist.front();
        }
        X& access()
        {
            return ref;
        }
    private:
        X& ref;
    };
    //etc
private:
    std::forward_list<X> Xlist;
    friend class XofC;
    //etc
}
```

**Problem:**
Having to pass everywhere XofC instances.

**2)**

```
class C
{
public:
    void newX(std::string);
    X& getX(std::string);
    //etc.
private:
    /*possible run-time mapping implementation
    std::vector<X> Xvec;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, decltype(Xvec.size())> NameMap;
    */
    //etc
}
```

**Problem:**
This does the job, but since all names of X (`std::string`) are known at compilation, the overhead of using run-time `std::unordered_map<std::string, decltype(Xvec.size())>` kind-of bugs me for something this simple.

Possible(*?*) solution: compile-time replacing of `std::string` with automatic index (`int`). Then I could use:

```
class C
{
public:
    void newX(int); //int: unique index calculated at compile time from std::string
    X& getX(int); //int: unique index calculated at compile time from std::string
//etc.
private:
    std::vector<X> Xvec;
}
```

### Questions:

1. Is there a **3)**?
2. Is a compile time solution possible for **2)**?
3. This is the real-life situation: I was starting my first C++ "project" and I thought I could use the practice and utility from an awesome user-friendly, simple and fast argument management library. I plan to make an `ArgMan` class which can parse the `argV` based on some specified switches. Switches would be named by the programmer descriptively and the trigger strings be specified (e.g. a switch named *recurse* could have `"-r"` and `"-recursive"` as triggers). When necessary, you should be easily able to get the setting of the switch. Implementation detail: `ArgMan` would have a `std::unordered_map<std::string/*a trigger*/, ??/*something linking to the switch to set on*/>`. This ensures an almost linear parse of `argV` relative to `argC`. How should I approach this?

Comment: If the names are fixed at compilation, you could make a enum with the various names and then store the instances in an array/vector and convert the enum to an index.

Answer (score 1):

You could 'abuse' non-type template arguments to get compiletime named instances:

- **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fe48d69b7188438)**

Assume we have a data class `X`:

```
#include <string> 

struct X
{
    int         has_some_properties;
    std::string data;
};
```

Now, for our named instances, we define some name constants. The trick is, to give them external linkage, so we can use the address as a non-type template argument.

```
// define some character arrays **with external linkage**
namespace Names
{
    extern const char Vanilla[] = "Vanilla";
    extern const char Banana [] = "Banana";
    extern const char Coconut[] = "Coconut";
    extern const char Shoarma[] = "Shoarma";
}
```

Now, we make a `NamedX` wrapper that takes a `const char*` non-type template argument. The wrapper holds a *static* instance of `X` (the *value*).

```
// now we can "adorn" a `namedX` with the name constants (above)
template <const char* Name>
   struct NamedX
{
    static X value;
};

template <const char* Name> X NamedX<Name>::value;
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    X& vanilla = NamedX<Names::Vanilla>::value;

    vanilla = { 42, "Woot!" };

    return vanilla.has_some_properties;
}
```

Note that due to the fact that the template arguments are *addresses*, no *actual* string comparison is done. You cannot, e.g. use

```
    X& vanilla = NamedX<"Vanilla">::value;
```

becuase `"Vanilla"` is a prvalue without external linkage. So, in fact you could do without some of the complexity and use tag structs instead: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ff6729015df4921)**

Answer (score 0):

While Neil's solution did what I asked for, it was too gimmicky to use in my library. Also, sehe's trick is surely useful, but, if I understood correctly, but doesn't seem related to my question. I have decided to emulate the desired behavior using method 1), here is a less broken attempt at it:

```
class C
{
private:
    class X
    {
        //std::string member;
        //etc
    };
public:
    class XofC
    {
    public:
        XofC(C & _mom) : mom(_mom)
        {
            mom.Xlist.emplace_front();
            tehX = &(Xlist.front());
        }
        X & get(maybe)
        {
            if (&maybe != &mom) throw std::/*etc*/;
            return &tehX;
        }
    private:
        X * tehX;
        C & mom;
    };
private:
    //etc
    std::forward_list<X> Xlist;
    friend class XofC;
    //etc
};
```

Usage:

```
C foo;
bar = C::XofC(foo); //acts like an instance of X, but stored in C, but you have to use:
bar.get(foo)/*reference to the actual X*/.member = "_1_";
```

Of course, the downside is you have to make sure you pass bar everywhere you need it, but works decently.
This is how it looks like in my tiny argument manager library:
https://raw.github.com/vuplea/arg_manager.h/master/arg_manager.h